# error deploying meteor app on heroku

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku

I have deployed my app on heroku and locally it works just fine, however when I open my app I get this message "Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."
when I type "heroku logs" I get this

```
2016-12-30T15:44:46.897189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-30T15:44:46.897612+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-30T15:44:46.897905+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2016-12-30T15:44:46.898079+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2016-12-30T15:44:46.898366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2016-12-30T15:44:46.898559+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-12-30T15:44:46.898734+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2016-12-30T15:44:46.898904+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899048+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! microscope@ start: `meteor run`
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899172+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899311+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899449+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the microscope@ start script 'meteor run'.
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899572+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899691+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the microscope package,
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899815+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-12-30T15:44:46.899940+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-12-30T15:44:46.900061+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     meteor run
2016-12-30T15:44:46.900422+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-12-30T15:44:46.900183+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-12-30T15:44:46.900301+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs microscope
2016-12-30T15:44:46.900543+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls microscope
2016-12-30T15:44:46.900664+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-12-30T15:44:46.903931+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:44:46.904248+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-30T15:44:46.904362+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-30T15:44:46.985527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-12-30T15:44:46.999587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-30T15:45:19.580505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hellohellohell.herokuapp.com request_id=33676d4a-942f-4621-b3e0-c3eaa486b0f1 fwd="41.217.180.223" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-30T15:45:23.940363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hellohellohell.herokuapp.com request_id=d9096c8d-16df-48b3-89a6-98cdf989150c fwd="41.217.180.223" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-30T15:48:05.018401+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-30T15:48:06.814270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-30T15:48:10.009640+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.009656+00:00 app[web.1]: > microscope@ start /app
2016-12-30T15:48:10.009657+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2016-12-30T15:48:10.009658+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.017655+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2016-12-30T15:48:10.033331+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-30T15:48:10.023737+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.033621+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-30T15:48:10.033903+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2016-12-30T15:48:10.034339+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2016-12-30T15:48:10.034605+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2016-12-30T15:48:10.034877+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-12-30T15:48:10.035062+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2016-12-30T15:48:10.035240+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2016-12-30T15:48:10.035417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! microscope@ start: `meteor run`
2016-12-30T15:48:10.035590+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2016-12-30T15:48:10.035809+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-12-30T15:48:10.035964+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the microscope@ start script 'meteor run'.
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036091+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the microscope package,
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036338+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036495+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036615+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     meteor run
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036738+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036857+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs microscope
2016-12-30T15:48:10.036979+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.037103+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls microscope
2016-12-30T15:48:10.037225+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-12-30T15:48:10.040737+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.040940+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-30T15:48:10.041058+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-30T15:48:10.159157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-30T15:48:10.123673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-12-30T15:48:15.546228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hellohellohell.herokuapp.com request_id=6b38141e-14fc-4c21-aae5-c89c077e83b9 fwd="41.217.180.223" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-30T15:48:16.814073+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hellohellohell.herokuapp.com request_id=8403ae63-2852-4da6-88f0-f539a0f11520 fwd="41.217.180.223" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-12-30T15:58:23.234351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-12-30T15:58:24.581443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-12-30T15:58:25.714966+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.714978+00:00 app[web.1]: > microscope@ start /app
2016-12-30T15:58:25.714979+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2016-12-30T15:58:25.714980+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.721137+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2016-12-30T15:58:25.725436+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.732613+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
2016-12-30T15:58:25.732802+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-12-30T15:58:25.732942+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.1
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733067+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733430+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733533+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! microscope@ start: `meteor run`
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733717+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733809+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-12-30T15:58:25.733903+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the microscope@ start script 'meteor run'.
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734066+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the microscope package,
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734247+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734328+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734412+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     meteor run
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734491+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734572+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs microscope
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734650+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734723+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls microscope
2016-12-30T15:58:25.737966+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.734832+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-12-30T15:58:25.738116+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-12-30T15:58:25.738194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-12-30T15:58:25.824057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-12-30T15:58:25.784111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting says that the meteor command is not found. This happens if your application doesn't have meteor listed as a dependency in your project's `package.json` file.

If you add meteor as a dependency to your project, then push this change up to Heroku, that will cause meteor to get installed, and it should now have access to the meteor command.

Comment: I got another error :\ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400865/failed-at-deploying-a-meteor-app-to-heroku

Comment: The other error is unrelated. It looks from your other SO post like there may be multiple issues with your project repo: dependencies are checked into source control, etc. You should prolly close this issue first and then have people answer the other one.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was resolved when using this build https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git and changing the package.json to

```
{
  "name": "microscope",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.2",
    "npm": "3.10.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you have to add the "engines" property? My package.json doesn't have it by default. Thx

Comment: @AlanWunsche I couldn't really tell why it worked eventually (because of the buildpack or because of the package.json change ,because I did the two together), but I can tell you right now that I have deleted the "engines" property of my package.json and it still worked. so it's probably the buildpack .. if you are still facing trouble debloying let me know , maybe I can help

Comment: I had this problem too.
In my case, I followed these instructions and configured this buildback: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

It worked after I did commit and push on git, and push on heroku using command line.