# Failed at deploying a meteor app to heroku

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku

I get the following error message when I try and deploy my meteor app to heroku
,anybody knows how to fix it ?

https://gist.github.com/amrshedou/a2a96ca479e8a9effa5a8f0ab175ddbb

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "microscope",
   "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
  "meteor": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://<username>:<password>@ meteor",

    "start": "meteor run"
  },

  "dependencies": {

    "meteor": "~0.5.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
```

**update**

the problem was resolved when using this build
https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
and changing the package.json to

```
{
  "name": "microscope",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.2",
    "npm": "3.10.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try this set of instructions, it works like a charm. https://medium.com/@gge/deploy-a-meteor-1-3-application-to-heroku-cda1f68ca20a

Comment: @NicholasByDesign Unfortunately I am getting the same error

Comment: Why your package.json says: "meteor": "~0.5.2", ???

Comment: @Giova.panasiti check this issue and you will understand why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399497/error-deploying-meteor-app-on-heroku